# Rendering an image from a MongoDB database using a mustache template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I am having issues in displaying the image on my "item.hjs" page. I think that the issue is the conversion in base64 from the database.

This is how I am rendering the information from the database using a mustache template in this way:

```
{{#items}}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <img src="data:{{Image.contentType}};base64,{{Image.data.toString('base64')}}">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{Title}}</h2>
      <p class="card-description">{{Description}}</p>
      <button class="trade-button">Trade</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/items}}

{{^items}}
  No entries yet.
{{/items}}
```

This code is only rendering the title and the description.

This is how I am passing on the information to the items page.

```
exports.show_items = function (req, res){
    Item.find({})
    .then(items => {
      res.render('items', { items: items });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.json({
        message: 'An error occurred while retrieving barters'
      })
    })
}
```

And this is how the information are stored on the MongoDB Database.

Items Database
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Mustache templating language does not allow you to put arbitrary JavaScript expressions inside mustaches. There *might* exist a particular Mustache implementation for JavaScript that does allow this as an extension, but I am not aware of such an implementation. That means that your problem is almost certainly in the `{{Image.data.toString('base64')}}` part. You could check the rendered HTML to verify that it looks different from what you expect.

Whenever something is not allowed by Mustache, the solution is nearly always to massage your data in the right shape beforehand. In your case, call `.toString` already in your JavaScript logic:

```js
function addBase64(item) {
    const image = item.Image;
    const base64 = image.data.toString('base64');
    return {...item, Image: {...image, base64}};
}

exports.show_items = function (req, res){
    Item.find({})
    .then(items => {
        res.render('items', { items: items.map(addBase64) });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.json({
            message: 'An error occurred while retrieving barters'
        })
    })
}
```

Now, you can just use the `base64` property in your template:

```
{{#items}}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <img src="data:{{Image.contentType}};base64,{{Image.base64}}">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{Title}}</h2>
      <p class="card-description">{{Description}}</p>
      <button class="trade-button">Trade</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/items}}

{{^items}}
  No entries yet.
{{/items}}
```